# Extended Permissions for Facebook MVC C#

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to get all the photos from a user's profile and i need to add that to the extended permissions of my Facebook MVC C# app.

I've tried using the following code below but i can't get it to work, i just get:

```
"This webpage has a redirect loop"
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to add extended permissions?

```
    [FacebookAuthorize(LoginUrl = "/Account/Login", Permissions = "user_photos")]
    public ActionResult Profile()
    {
        var client = new FacebookWebClient();
        dynamic photos = client.Get("me/photos");
        dynamic me = client.Get("me/photos");
        ViewBag.Name = me.name;
        ViewBag.Id = me.id;

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like someone to correct me if i'm not right, but, extended permissions are specified either on the login button, or the permissions button.

For example, I have the login button on my Default.aspx page:

```html
<fvk:loginbutton id ="loginbutton1" runat="server" OnConnectCalled="OnLogin" Permissions="email,user_birthday,publish_stream,user_photos" Size="small" />
```

That is where I specify what permissions my app needs. And after that I can specify inside my code, what info I need to retrieve in a specific moment. Default.aspx.cs.

```cs
var client = new FacebookWebClient();
dynamic photos = client.Get("me/photos");
dynamic me = client.Get("me/photos");
ViewBag.Name = me.name;
ViewBag.Id = me.id;
```

This way, when the user first logs into your app, he gives the requested permissions. Then afterwards, you can use his info / photos anyway you want in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I just did that exact same thing using this:

```
[CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = "user_photos,publish_stream", CancelUrlPath = "/Home/NoPermission", ReturnUrlPath = "/Photos/Upload")]
```

I'm not sure the difference between FacebookAuthorize and CanvasAuthorize. What might help is setting the REturnUrlPath. I did it because I'm working locally on a virtual directory and it wasn't redirecting correctly after authentication.

Comment: Problem is I rather have my controller define the permissions rather than have the permissions hard-coded on the view...

Comment: I think I've tried putting the CanvasAuthorize attribute on the controller instead of the action and ran into problems. From the apps I've built, I've found it rare that you need the same permissions for every action in a controller. Either the actions require different permissions from each other, or there are usually some that don't require permissions at all. In either case, are you able to fix your redirect loop issue with the attribute on a single action?